# Function has 'Object required' issue, runs fine if made a sub

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: calling function added to bottom of the code

I've written a code which looks at two separate workbooks and compares data between them to remove duplicated data from one of the workbooks. The code works perfectly fine as a sub, but i want it to work as a function so i can call it for other workbooks as well. when i run it as a function, i get an 'object required' error, but i can't identify where from. The only change i made was removing the variables from the code and putting them into the header (not sure what its official name is, but the data on the same line as the title). In the code below I've left in the variables as if it were a sub for reference, but when running as a function they're removed. Any idea where the error could be coming from?

```
    Public Function removedupes(wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, month As Range, cell As Range)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    'define variables
    'Dim wb1 As Workbook
    'Dim wb2 As Workbook
    'Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    'Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim itemmatch As Range
    'Dim cell As Range
    'Dim month As Range
    Dim firstmatch As String
    Dim item As Long
     
    'Set wb1 = Workbooks("workbook 1")
    'Set wb2 = Workbooks("workbook 2")
    'Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("sheet 1")
    'Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("sheet 2")
    'Set month = ws1.Range("A:A")

    'finds matching item numbers
    With month
    'Set cell = ws2.Range("B3")
    Do Until cell.Value = 0
    item = cell.Value
    Set itemmatch = .Find(item, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not itemmatch Is Nothing Then
    'deletes dupelicate cells
                itemmatch.Resize(1, 12).Delete shift:=xlUp
                Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
                item = cell.Value
        Else
            Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Loop
    End With
    
    End Function
```

This is how I am calling the function:

```
    removedupes Workbooks("workbook 1"), Workbooks("workbook 2"), wb1.Worksheets("worksheet 1"), wb2.Worksheets("worksheet 2"), ws1.Range("A:A"), ws2.Range("B3")
```

Comment: What does wrong when you remove the line `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: How are you trying to use this function? Probably something wrong with how you're passing the variables to the function. Also, a function is supposed to return a value, this would be better done as just a sub. (subs can be used in different workbooks as well if you have it in your personal)

Comment: @Dominique - the same thing happens if i remove the error handler

Comment: @Notus_Panda - i want the code to look delete a cells from spreadsheet 1 if the line already exists in spreadsheet 2. I've just tried the code as a sub but with the variables changeable and it has the same problem as when i run it as a function. you'll have to excuse me as I'm not very proficient at vba.

Comment: Why are you commenting out the declarations and definitions of variables? As you are working with 2 workbooks you must qualify all your references by uncommenting these lines. At the moment you are neither declaring nor defining `month`, but you are using it in the `With` statement. You are also not declaring `cell` as a `Range` nor are you setting it.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry i commented them out as they are not used when i run it. These variables are set when the function is called by another macro. i left them in so that you can see what they're set as and how it was laid out when it worked fine as a sub.

Comment: Try to remove the casting in your function parameters. Your cell is sent to a range, but you are using Cell.Value = 0. A range does not have a .value . You can see how to use ranges in the msdocs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/looping-through-a-range-of-cells
for example
 For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells 
  c.Value 0 1 ' What it is you are doing with it 
 Next

Comment: Could you share an example of a calling procedure (of how you are calling it) so we can accurately fix this one to work for your convenience? Just copy it to the bottom of your post. BTW, *spreadsheet* is another word for workbook (a file).

Comment: OK sorry, I see what you're doing. As @VBasic2008 asked, please share how you're calling the function. The convention in VBA is to use a function when you're returning a value (which you're not doing here). You can still pass arguments to a subroutine.

Comment: Also please please tell us which line is causing this error. When you get the error, press Debug, then keep pressing F8 until the error occurs again.

Comment: Not sure about you, but I've been using `.Value` on a range (with success) quite a lot @OrigamiEye both `Range()` and `Cells()` have a `.Value`

Comment: @VBasic2008 I've added the calling procedure to the bottom of the code. And yes, the function calls from two different workbooks.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I've tried swapping the function out for a sub but still get the same error. however, it is good to know that a function is for returning values, thank you. i can't debug unfortunately as the variables aren't within the code. nothing happens when i try to debug.

Comment: @OrigamiEye I've been using `Range.Value`  for a while and it works fine, as i said before this code runs fine when the variables are within the code. it identifies the value as i want it to.

Comment: A more reasonable call would be `RemoveDupes "Workbook 1", "Workbook 2", "Worksheet 1", "Worksheet 2", "A:A", "B3"`. Set the objects (workbooks, worksheets and ranges) in the Sub whose signature (*the official name*) could be `Sub RemoveDupes(ByVal WorkbookName1 As String, ByVal WorkbookName2 As String, ByVal SheetName1 as String, ByVal SheetName2 As String, ByVal RangeAddress1 As String, ByVal RangeAddress2 As String)`. Start with `Set wb1 = Workbooks(WorkbookName1): Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(SheetName1): Set rg1 =ws1.Range(RangeAddress1)`... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I know why this is happening.

This is how you need to call your function/subroutine

```
  Dim wb1 As Workbook
  Dim wb2 As Workbook
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim month As Range
  Dim cell As Range
  
  Set wb1 = Workbooks("workbook 1")
  Set wb2 = Workbooks("workbook 2")
  Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("worksheet 1")
  Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("worksheet 2")
  Set month = ws1.Range("A:A")
  Set cell = ws2.Range("B3")
  removedupes wb1, wb2, ws1, ws2, month, cell
```

If you don't want to declare variables, then you can call it like this:

```
removedupes Workbooks("workbook 1"), _
            Workbooks("workbook 2"), _
            Workbooks("workbook 1").Sheets("worksheet 1"), _
            Workbooks("workbook 2").Sheets("worksheet 2"), _
            Workbooks("workbook 1").Sheets("worksheet 1").Range("A:A"), _
            Workbooks("workbook 2").Sheets("worksheet 2").Range("B3")
```

You cannot use a function argument to define another argument in the calling statement.

*Please note* the `_` is the line continuation character in VBA. It allows us to split a long line into multiple lines for readability.

By the way, in your function all you need to pass are the `cell` and `month` variables. So your function can be simplified as:

```
Public Function removedupes(month As Range, cell As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    'define variables
    Dim itemmatch As Range
    Dim firstmatch As String
    Dim item As Long

    'finds matching item numbers
    With month
      Do Until cell.Value = 0
          item = cell.Value
          Set itemmatch = .Find(item, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
          If Not itemmatch Is Nothing Then
              'deletes dupelicate cells
              itemmatch.Resize(1, 12).Delete shift:=xlUp
              Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
              item = cell.Value
          Else
              Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
          End If
      Loop
    End With
End Function
```

And you can call it like this:

```
removedupes Workbooks("workbook 1").Sheets("worksheet 1").Range("A:A"), _
            Workbooks("workbook 2").Sheets("worksheet 2").Range("B3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take for example any test workbook (in my case "Map3") where you have this in the `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("other")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Dim rngMonth As Range: Set rngMonth = ws.Range("A1:A10")
    Dim rngCell As Range: Set rngCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!removedupes", ActiveWorkbook, wb, ActiveSheet, ws, rngMonth, rngCell
End Sub
```

Then you can keep the sub `removedupes` in your personal and call it like you did in the above code while being able to pass variables as defined in your sub.

In personal:

```
Sub removedupes(wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, month As Range, cell As Range)

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim itemmatch As Range
    Dim firstmatch As String
    Dim item As Long
    
    'finds matching item numbers
    With month
    'Set cell = ws2.Range("B3")
    Do Until cell.Value = 0
    item = cell.Value
    Set itemmatch = .Find(item, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not itemmatch Is Nothing Then
    'deletes dupelicate cells
                itemmatch.Resize(1, 12).Delete shift:=xlUp
                Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
                item = cell.Value
        Else
            Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

I had everything the same in "other" as I had it in "Map3" and let it run once:
[image: test run]

I hope this was what you were looking for :)

P.S.: You can also add a reference to your personal workbook via Tools in the VBE but this way is fastest of course.

Comment: Thank you! this almost worked for me. my code is running from the opposite workbooks which made it a little bit awkward, but i determined my variables within the sub i called it from (as you did) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: You could use something like `Application.Run wb.Name & "!removedupes"` then if I'm not mistaken. If it worked, feel free to accept the answer that is most correct to your situation, Super Symmetry for example is correct that you didn't need to pass the workbooks/worksheets variables if you're not further using them in the sub.

Answer (score 0):

Editing what Notus_Panda commented, I set the variables within the sub calling the removedupes sub, then called the variables from the same sub. I no longer get object required errors and have tested it with other workbooks as well. Thank you all!

The sub that is calling the variables is shown below.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = Workbooks("workbook 1")
Dim wb2 As Workbook: Set wb2 = Workbooks("workbook 2")
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("worksheet 1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("worksheet 2")
Dim month As Range: Set month = ws1.Range("A:A")
Dim cell As Range: Set cell = ws2.Range("B3")
removedupes wb1, wb2, ws1, ws2, month, cell
End Sub
```

the code for the removedupes sub is shown below.

```
Public Sub removedupes(wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, month As Range, cell As Range)

On Error Resume Next
Dim itemmatch As Range
Dim firstmatch As String
Dim item As Long
'finds matching item numbers
With month
Do Until cell.Value = 0
item = cell.Value
Set itemmatch = .Find(item, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not itemmatch Is Nothing Then
'deletes dupelicate cells
            itemmatch.Resize(1, 12).Delete shift:=xlUp
            Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
            item = cell.Value
    Else
        Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Loop
End With

End Sub
```